# Distribution of the partial likelihood ratio test in Cox model?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, cox-model, likelihood-ratio, chi-squared-distribution

If I replace the **partial likelihood** of the Cox model

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model#The_Cox_model

instead of the **likelihood** in the **likelihood ratio test**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test

What is the distribution of this test statistic? Is it still $\chi^2_q$?

Answer (score 1):

The partial likelihood ratio test is asymptotically $\chi^2_q$ as well, under conditions that guarantee consistency and asymptotic normality of the partial maximum likelihood estimators. This is a standard result in several textbooks.

See for instance these lecture notes:

[https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~dzhang2/st745/chap6.pdf](https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/%7Edzhang2/st745/chap6.pdf)

or the book

> ANDERSEN, P.K., Borgan, Ø., Gill, R.D., and Keiding, N., [Statistical Models Based on Counting Processes](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-4348-9), Springer, 1993.